# I am trying to verify if an email actually exists by first resolving its DNS, then check if the email is valid using the below code:

Tags: python, email, email-validation

```
def checkEmailState(email):
    fromAddress = 'mislam162013@bscse.uiu.ac.bd'

    # Get domain for DNS lookup
    splitAddress = email.split('@')
    domain = str(splitAddress[1])

    try:
        # MX record lookup
        records = dns.resolver.resolve(domain, 'MX')
        mxRecord = records[0].exchange
        mxRecord = str(mxRecord)

        # SMTP lib setup (use debug level for full output)
        server = smtplib.SMTP()
        server.set_debuglevel(0)

        # SMTP Conversation
        server.connect(mxRecord)
        server.helo(server.local_hostname)  ### server.local_hostname(Get local server hostname)
        server.mail(fromAddress)
        code, message = server.rcpt(str(email))
        server.quit()
    except smtplib.SMTPServerDisconnected:
        return 'Success'
    except TimeoutError:
        return 'Success'
    except dns.resolver.NoAnswer:
        return 'Bad'
    except UnicodeError:
        return 'Bad'
    except:
        return 'Bad'
```

When connecting server `server.connect(MX record)`, it is taking a long time. No error response is occurring. I have tried to terminate the execution of this line when taking too long using socket. But it is not working. Need some suggestion on how can I terminate and return from the fuction mentioned when execution time takes more than a given duration.

Comment: the SMTP() class method takes a timeout value.

Comment: try this: server = smtplib.SMTP(timeout=10) ref : https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html

Comment: What are you trying to do? Even if you find the mx server, that doesn't mean the address is valid. Most mail servers won't let you check whether an address is valid, as to not help spammers. Your best bet is to deliver an email and check if that bounces. If you bought an email list from somewhere, discard it; don't try to get subscribers that way. If you have people sign up for your service, send them a welcome mail and have them click a link to confirm they want to receive mail from you. Only after that confirmation add them to your subscription list. This is also GDPR compliant.